# Can I avoid CRLF injection attacks by replacing JUST the CR?

Tags: php, security, email, sanitization, newline

I have a form which allows one file attachment, and generates an email to a hard-coded address.  I would like to avoid the possibility of malicious users entering custom mail headers (a CRLF injection, so called since email headers end in \r\n as per RFC).

Suppose I run the following function on every piece of data which might make it into the [$additional_headers](http://php.net/mail#refsect1-function.mail-parameters) parameter:

```
<?php

function strip_crlf($string){ return str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $string); }

?>
```

That replaces JUST the carriage return half of the CRLF pair.  Will that prevent potential attacks adequately?

Ordinarily I would just replace the \r\n with an empty string.  But this particular form allows for one attachment, which means that the message body actually winds up getting passed through the $additional_headers parameter since PHP doesn't have a native function for building a multipart MIME encoded email (that I know of).

In case anyone cares, here's my function for mailing an attachment:

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $message, $file = false, $filename = false, $filetype = false){

    // Remove CRLF sequences from everything that might go into a header
    $from = strip_crlf($from);
    $from_name = strip_crlf($from_name);
    $message = strip_crlf($message);
    if($filename){ $filename = strip_crlf($filename); }
    if($filetype){ $filetype = strip_crlf($filetype); }

    // $to and $subject escaping handled natively by mail();
    // $file is base64 encoded before mail_attachment() is called.

    $header = '';

    // No file attachment; just send a regular email.
    if(!$file){
        $header .= "From: ".$from_name." <".$from.">\r\n";
        return mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    }

    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    // Build a MIME encoded message.
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$uid\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--$uid\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "$message\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--$uid\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$filename\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "$file\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--$uid--";

    // Send the mail.
    return mail($to, $subject, '', $header);
}

?>
```

Comment: `strip_crlf("\r\r\n")` becomes `"\r\n"`

Comment: Ooo, good catch!  My strip function wouldn't have worked reliably even if I could count on email servers to honor the convention.  +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, replacing just the CR is not sufficient - there are enough mail clients which only look at the LF that it can be exploited. Of course, most of the header fields don't need newlines *at all*, so you can simply strip both CR and LF from everything but `$message`. For `$message`, either make sure it can't contain your MIME seperator (`--$uid` in this case), or encode it as base64 or something.

Comment: I'm going to accept this one, since it answers the question directly.  I may follow the Swiftmailer/PHPMailer advice, though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you're worried about injections, then don't build your own messages. Use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com), which take care of all those worries for you.